# Get time stamps for stack in crash dump

Tags: debugging, windbg, dump, crash-dumps

I have a process that crashes unexpectedly.
About the same time the crash occurs, I see an error in the log infrastructure process and then it softly shut down.

I'm trying to understand which of the processes is causing the problem, the log infra getting my process crash or the other way around.

In order to do that, I'm looking at the crash dump my process produced (taken with adplus) and trying to understand, at what time exactly the first exit-related method was called, then compare it with the log infra error time and shutdown time.

How can I do that, is there a way to get, method calls time stamp, in stack?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attach WinDbg or start your app with WinDbg and change the show time stamps parameter:

```
.echotimestamps 1
```

This will insert timestamps into the output for all events such as exceptions, thread creations etc.. see this [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562933%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) link.

I would also write a log to disk immediately once WinDbg attaches:

```
.logopen c:\temp\mylog.txt
```

to capture the output, this should achieve what you want.